# GWT: How to use Constants in UiBinder Template

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

I have a question related to UiBinder.

I have the following UiBinder file:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
             xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">
    <g:HTMLPanel>
        <div>
            <g:VerticalPanel>
                <g:Label>Please enter your password:</g:Label>
                <g:FlowPanel>
                    <g:PasswordTextBox ui:field="textbox"/>
                    <g:Button ui:field="button" text="Login" styleName="?????"/>
                </g:FlowPanel>
            </g:VerticalPanel>
        </div>
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

If I put the style name in the ???, it works fine.

However, We have a constant file (not i18n Constants) which contains all the css names as constants. Like:

```
public class CSSConstants {
    public static final String CSS_TITLE = "title";

    public static final String CSS_TEXT_NORMAL = "text_normal";
    public static final String CSS_TEXT_ERROR = "text_error";
    public static final String CSS_TEXT_ERROR = "button blue";
    .......
}
```

I want to know how I can refer to this constant file in the UiBinder Template?

Many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope this will work for you:
1) In your Java class, define a static getter for your style-name:

```
public static String getSomeStyle(){}
```

2) Access your style name as following:

```
 <ui:with type="package.of.your.class.ClassName" field="yourClass"></ui:with>

<g:Button ui:field="button" text="Login" styleName="{yourClass.getSomeStyle}"/>
```

This works fine when accessing targetHistoryToken values, and I hope it will work in your case.

Of course you can do that easily (and elegantly) using interfaces that extend ClientBundle, but I don't think that's what you want (correct me if I misunderstood your need, so I can give more hints).

(Sorry I don't have a dev environment to test it before posting my answer)

Comment: styleName="yourClass.getSomeStyle" must be with {} - styleName="{yourClass.getSomeStyle}".

Comment: yes of course sorry. Answer edited

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I think this will work but I now think it is better to put hard coded style name into the UiBinder template file as IntelliJ support automatic complete if I put the style name directly but won't do so if I use a constant file :). I am sure this will be useful in other scenarios in the future.